# Filling areas using transparent color without affecting the border

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am drawing a figure which shows several tetrahedrons in Illustrator. I have drawn all the line segments and connected them at the endpoints. Now the figure has been like this.

Now I want to fill the areas surrounded by the line segments. I did this as follows: first selected 3 line segments, `join` them and fill the color.

However, I found another problem. Since there are dashed lines in this figure, if the 3 line segments contains one which is dashed, the `join` operation will cause all the lines dashed. That is what I don't want.

So What is the correct operation if I want to meet my purpose?
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the layers panel showing the shapes?

Comment: There should be only one layer here. Please see the updated figure.

Answer (score 0):

I answer the question as I understand the task, thus probably there can be some inaccuracies in the answer.

If I understand you properly, you want to fill by color all the surfaces enclosed by solid lines.

For this task I would hide all the dashed lines, select All the solid lines and Expand them.

Next, I'd Unite them to create Compound shape.

Finally, I'd fill the surfaces with colors adjusting all the properties of the fills as needed.

At the end, unhiding the dashed lines should give you the desired "3d" look.

**NB!** *If you don't want to play with Opacities - Place all dashed lines above the solid ones in the Layers panel.*